# how to add state wise tax charge without adding customer and product class

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6, mage

my question is bit technical. i want to ask if i belong to state named NJ, and i want apply tax rule only on this state, means if user selects NJ on checkout as its billing state it should charge him 7% extra in checkout. i have made the tax rule as well but unable to implement on front end. i want this without influence of product and customer class. if i am wrong please give me proper direction with step by step guide. i am using magento 1.8.0. 
please help........................
what sort of custom code need to include or should be wrote by me??
no more lucks please so give me guide..

Comment: my simple purpose is only that if as user i choose NJ as my state in checkout it adds 7% tax and just add it in final net amount as well. for all other it act like normal order but for NJ it should show and adds as well....simply this thing please

Comment: Why can't you use product and customer classes? Out of the box Magento has a defaults for these and could charge tax to 1 or multiple customer groups and a product has to be considered a taxable good for tax to be applicable. You can charge tax without adding or creating any customer groups, and the only thing that would have to be done on the product level is setting the products tax class to "taxable goods". If you need help setting up tax the way Magento does it out of the box I will be glad to do so.

Comment: @Rob i have used all the options as you said and even i have read all the guides on this please but still unable to show the tax deductions only for NJ. can you please please please show me the step by step guide for this??? so i can roll up this stuff please. please give me step by step guide. i will be thank ful to you.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** create sales tax rules for different states :

**Process :-** Go to Sales -> Taxes -> Manage Tax Zones & Rates . Add your taxation for different states here.

**2)** Manage Tax Rules :

**Process :-** Go to Sales -> Taxes -> Manage Tax rules. If you haven't created rule, create and check all your tax rules for that. Keep the product Tax class as "Taxable goods".

**3)** Apply Tax Rules :

**Process :-** System -> Configuration -> Tax. (Under Sales Tab). After this, change your **"Tax Class for Shipping"** from None to **"Taxable goods".**

Your rules will be applied accordingly for different states.